# Scaling issues with LUMINANCE_ALPHA

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

I'm currently extending my OpenGL-UI system, for this i rewrite the font part and faced a issue which appears when using mipmapping. Because of the fact that images say more than thousands of words:

[image: Font issue]

As you can see the font's transparency is fading out ( the text should be displayed 8 times! ), this happens only when using `LUMINANCE_ALPHA`-textures. The code which loads the textures is basically the same but they differ in the formats used, this is what `LUMINANCE_ALPHA` uses:

> TexImageInternalFormat.LUMINANCE_ALPHA, TexImageFormat.LUMINANCE_ALPHA, TexImagePixelType.UNSIGNED_BYTE

Linear filtering is enabled and clamp is set to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. For me it seems like a mipmapping issue but i tried a lot of different settings and it isn't working and, as i already said, RGBA textures are working without any issues. The application also runs on iOS so using a `LUMINANCE_ALPHA`-texture saves a lot of ram compared to a RGBA.

What could cause this and how can i solve it?

Comment: How do you generate your mipmaps?

Comment: Do you have enabled lighting?

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure. And checked the colors of the mipmaps.

Comment: @Luca I don't use the FFP so i do not have lightning enabled.

Comment: @FelixK.: I asked *how* you generate your mipmaps. I don't know how "sure" answers that question. Do you generate them online or offline? What tool do you use? Etc.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh sorry i'm a little bit tired right now ( Just woke up ). I generated them with the PVRTexTool ( newest Version ) which i actually also use when generating the mipmaps for the other textures. After generation i also checked if the mipmaps are ok. I could upload them.

Comment: I could downvote myself, seems the reads 4 bytes for each pixel instead of two bytes. Checked everything but not this. Thanks @NicolBolas you gave me the right idea.

Comment: @FelixK. - Feel free to post that as an answer and accept it so that others can find this easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out the `ImageFormat` settings have been wrong:

```
LA8 = new ImageFormat("LA8", TexImageInternalFormat.LUMINANCE_ALPHA, TexImageFormat.LUMINANCE_ALPHA, TexImagePixelType.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 4);
```

The last number indicates the number of bytes per pixel for this format and should be 2 in case of `LUMINANCE_ALPHA`. The PVR reader doesn't complain about the missing image data and no exception has been thrown. Changing the 4 to 2 solves the problem.